# How to compensate 'Ego-Motion'

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I am doing a project to detect moving object from a moving camera with optical flow. To detect the real motion of any moving object I need compensate the ego-motion of the camera. Can any body suggest  a simple way to do so? I use opencv c and c++ for my project.

Comment: Same question in reddit [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/computervision/comments/dwnirr/is_it_possible_to_use_optical_flow_from_mooving/)

Comment: just saw that, but this question was asked in 2012, if you see the date here.

Comment: Big LOL! I didn't know at that time there was even computer vision exist :P

Comment: hahahaha.. yes it was there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi actually if you use optical flow you not ecessarily need to compensate the ego-motion. It is possible to create long term trajectories and cluster them. Look at these publications [LDOF](http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/Publications/2010/Bro10e/) or [MORLOF](http://elvera.nue.tu-berlin.de/typo3/list.php?id=1366). But if you want to copensate the ego-motion than:

- detect points to track using GFT or simple a point grid
- compute motion vector via Lucas Kanade or other local optical flow methods
- compute the affine or perspective transformation matrix using cv::getAffineTransform or cv::getPerspectiveTransform (RANSAC is a good estimator)
- compensate ego-motion with the transformation matrix by using cv::warpAffine or cv::warpPerspective